# wget doesn’t run in crontab in linux?

Tags: linux, wget, cron

I have this command I want to run once every day with my QNAP NAS (linux):

```
wget 'http://url.link' -O catalog/output.file
```

In terminal it works fine and the file is downloading but when adding it to crontab it doesn´t download.

I have tried this line in crontab:

```
08 20 * * * wget 'http://url.link' -O catalog/output.file
```

Can someone help me why this isn´t downloading at 20.08?

Comment: The environment in `crontab` is different from that in a terminal. Try putting full paths to both `wget` and `output.file`, and redirect output to a log file by adding `>>/FullPath/wget.log 2>&1` to the `crontab` entry.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
crontab /etc/config/crontab && /etc/init.d/crond.sh restart
```